# Log changes to a model with Librato

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, librato

I have a Devise model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise ::trackable
```

I'd like to see the number of times an `Account` is created and signed in to, in Librato.

Answer (score 0):

Using Librato's [log stream parsing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/librato#custom-log-based-metrics) you can record the events with a `$stdout.puts`.

I recommend extracting this log to a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), and using [model callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to monitor changes.

We can create a file in `lib/librato/account.rb`:

```
module Librato
  module Account
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      after_create do
        $stdout.puts 'count#account.create=1'
      end

      after_save if: :current_sign_in_at_changed? do
        $stdout.puts 'count#account.sign_in=1'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then include it in your model, thus:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Librato::Account
```